C# source generators: possible to redirect navigation in IDE to origin?
I have a use case where my source generator is reading for specific const string instances that are tagged with a particular attribute.  Think of these as templates.
The source generator processes these templates and generates a class from the const string effectively creating a strongly typed template class.
Now let's say that I have a const string like this:
const string StateCapitol = "...";

This will generate a class like via the source generator:
public class StateCapitolPrompt {
  // ...
}

And the user can create an instance like this:
var capitol = await new StateCapitolPrompt("NJ").ExecuteAsync();

In VS Code, the source navigation will fail when the user clicks through StateCapitolPrompt in the example above.  Is there some way to instruct the IDE/language server that when the user navigates StateCapitolPrompt to redirect to the user declared const string StateCapitol?  Perhaps some Attribute that I could use to decorate the class?
